# Check permissions?

Tags: php, mysql

How do people usually verify that the information being fetched from a database is indeed related to the active user?

For example: let's say we list a group of PMs inside user x's inbox - how do I make sure that only user x can fetch something from the inbox, and not someone else (this would be done by "hacking" the address ofcourse).

Obviously I could just compare the active username with what is in the database table, but is there no easy way I can control this globally somehow, without having to compare the active username with hundreds of different tables for different actions?

Comment: That should be the way to do it or else $_SESSION key! else the very expensive way...create different database and tables separately for each user(That would be stressful isn't it?).

Comment: While you are at it just purchase every user a server.

Comment: Also, look up the difference in programming between `Authentication` and `Authorisation`. You need to first authenticate your user to prove their id, then once done authorise them to check their inbox (but not others)

Comment: Got it! I think it's more clear to me know. I think I'll do fine from here, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Supposedly you're fetching the messages *of the logged in user* to begin with, no? Something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `recipient` = '$loggedInUserId'"
```

If so, I don't understand the question. If that's not what you're doing, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes. But what I'm wondering is, if there's a way to control such things **globally**, not by using new queries for each function.

Comment: @Nisto If you need the messages, you are going to have to query for them. What do you mean by `using new queries for each function`? You didn't supply us with any function

Comment: @Nisto Then no. Your database doesn't know anything about your users, so you can't tell it "whatever I'm going to query on, I always mean only the current user". That's not how it works, and it's most likely not what you want either. The best you can do is make your own wrapper objects/functions that *automatically* inject the user id into the query.

Answer (score 2):

Well your application tracks users sessions, and ensures security. I.e. when user logins server sets cookie with session id, and by session variable your server upon request of page will know what user is really requesting something(or maybe no logged in user at all if there is no cookie), thus your application may use user id from session and request url to figure out if it should show what is requested, or show error message or redirect because user is trying to access what is not his. Of course this is a bit more involving but thats a start. I suggest reading on php sessions and cookies.

Answer (score 1):

That is what database query conditionals are for... only selecting the relative data.

Generally once the person is logged in you would get their username and password from `$_SESSION` variables, query the database to make sure they are a valid user, then grab whatever you need using a `WHERE username = '$username'`